# How to set programmatically cookies using Crosswalk XWalkView?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I need to make a webview application that POST a username and password and then display the webpage logged-in. I must use cookies but i chouldn't find how to do it, tried the traditional ways but nothing.

Has anyone had any experience with xWalkView and how to get/put cookies ?

(I am using xWalkView since the traditional webview on android 4.2.2 can't load HTML5 webpages)

Comment: Why not do that using JavaScript or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I did not find the exact answer. Instead, I found a kind of a work around. 
As I am using a servlet container, I append a ";jsessionid=" to every request I make to the server.
The other thing than can actually work for you regardless of what backend you use is to make a request to your web server so that it returns a response with a cookie.
For example if you want to add a name=test you could make some xhr request to some url and the response must have the cookie name=test in it. This technique also work for me for session tracking in my java app. 
Good luck